# Tool for obtaining a BibTeX entry from a key, without creating it manually

Tags: citations, tools, google-scholar, bibtex

I am looking for a tool, where I only need to write something like `alessandroni2015bibtex` (this very question) to obtain the BibTeX entry, without needing to rewrite it.

I am aware that Google Scholar always offers a BibTeX link and uses `AuthorYearFirst_Word` as a scheme, but I do not know how to use this key for searching, because Google uses an internal ID for each BibTeX. Thus, when I feed the data of my citation to Google Scholar, sometimes I do not find it. For example, in case of books, I find only new editions (maybe due to a wrong use of the tool).

Comment: If you have the DOI, you can retrieve it through the API. `curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/pr100594k`

Comment: Thank you @Davidmh, I have just tested your script... under Windows, and it runs. ;-)

Comment: In mathematics, MathSciNet has bibtex informations. You can just copy and paste into your Latex file.

Comment: Doesn't this question probably belong to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Please don't vote to close->migrate to meta if you want to migrate a question to another site. Just close as off topic for "other" reason and leave a comment. The close->migrate to meta path *actually migrates the question to meta*, which is certainly undesirable here.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent As for whether it actually belongs on [TeX.se]; it's probably on-topic there. On the other hand, it's not a technical question about LaTeX (which would be off topic here), but a question asking for a software tool. So it's not any more or less on topic than any of the other [tag:tools] questions, just because it happens to be about bibtex.

Comment: I already had a partial answer (using the DOI). Of course a tool that gives me the BibTeX (or BibLaTeX, that I do not use, but someone yes) by the knowledge of Author, Year of publication and Title I think that is helpful for all. Of course, If is possible, I can ask to also [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Don't cross-post to two SE sites at once, that's against the rules. Now that this is reopened, you can wait and see if it gets an answer, or you can flag and ask a moderator to migrate it to TeX (if you don't think you'll get an answer here)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about BibTeX and APIs, not academia - might be on-topic at [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) (*certainly* not on meta!).

Comment: Ok @StephanKolassa, tell me what I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it. In all but the most verbose or non-human friendly (e.g., DOI) [key style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884886/what-are-some-good-bibtex-key-conventions), the problem is a one-to-many mapping in that each BibTeX key maps to many sources even though any single source has just a single BibTex key. Even in relatively small personal bib files, conflicting keys are common and need to be disambiguated (usually with an additional letter or number).  The bigger the database (and Goggle Scholar is a big database) means that there will be lots of collisions.

Comment: Ok, In also my opinion this question is close at off topic. Is interesting for all, but is important a deep knowledge of LaTeX for a good answer. And now: which it is the procedure for move it?

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni I don't see how knowing TeX is needed to answer this. Maybe software recs. I asked on chat to see if we can get an idea. I think it fits here.